# Properties of $A\mapsto (A\cap X, Y\setminus (A\cap Y))$ given $X,Y\neq\emptyset$ and $X\cap Y\neq \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets with $X\cap Y\neq \emptyset$ and
$$F:\wp(X\cup Y)\to \wp(X)\times \wp(Y),\,A\mapsto (A\cap X, Y\setminus (A\cap Y)).$$

---

**Claim.** $F$ is not surjective since $(\emptyset, \emptyset)\not\in F(\wp(X\cup Y))$.

*Proof.* Let $A\cap X=\emptyset$ thus $A=Y\setminus X$. Therefore
$$Y\setminus (A\cap Y) = Y\setminus ((Y\setminus X)\cap Y) = Y\setminus (Y\setminus X) = X\cap Y\neq \emptyset$$
hence $(\emptyset, \emptyset)\not\in F(\wp(X\cup Y))$.

---

**Claim.** $F$ is injective.

Unfortunately I struggle to show $$(A\cap X, Y\setminus (A\cap Y)) = (B\cap X, Y\setminus (B\cap Y))\implies A=B$$ to prove that $F$ is injective. Any suggestions on that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Proof.* Let $A\cap X=\emptyset$ thus $A=Y\setminus X$.

This is false. If $A\cap X=\emptyset$, then you cannot conclude that. You can only conclude $A\subseteq Y\setminus X$.

---

For injectivity, the proof by mr. chip is the easiest way to go, but if you want, you can go the long way around:

Take $x\in A$. Then there are two options:

1. $x\in X$. In this case, $x\in X\cap A$, and since $X\cap A=X\cap B$, we have $x\in X\cap B$, therefore $x\in B$.
2. $x\notin X$. In this case, $x\in Y$, meaning $x\notin Y\setminus A$. But since $Y\setminus A=Y\setminus B$, that means $x\notin Y\setminus B$. Since we already know $x\in Y$, assuming $x\notin B$ would mean $x\in Y\setminus B$ which is not true. Therefore, $x\in B$.

So, we can conclude $x\in A\implies x\in B$ meaning $A\subseteq B$. Since the argument is symmetrical, we can just reverse $A$ and $B$ to get $B\subseteq A$, therefore $A=B$.

Comment: In 2. you say $x\not\in X\implies x\in Y$. Shouldn't that be $x\in Y\setminus X$ more precisely?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Sure, but I don' really need $x\in Y\setminus X$. All I need is $x\in Y$, so that's what I'm going with. It's not true, even though some other even more precise statement is also true.

Comment: Alright, I'd like to know whether your suggest going along with $A\subset Y\setminus X$ to prove the claim about $F$ not being surjective or should I go about it differently?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic I think you are on the right track, you just need to modify the proof a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G:\wp(X)\times\wp(Y)\to\wp(X\cup Y)$ be prescribed by: $$\langle A,B\rangle\mapsto A\cup B^{\complement}$$

Then: $$G(F(C))=G(\langle C\cap X,(C\cap Y)^{\complement}\rangle)=(C\cap X)\cup(C\cap Y)=C$$

So $F$ has a left-inverse, hence is injective: $$F(P)=F(Q)\implies P=G(F(P))=G(F(Q))=Q$$

Comment: Probably the most elegant way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

$A = (A \cap X) \cup (A \cap Y) = (A \cap X) \cup Y \setminus (Y \setminus (A \cap Y)) = (B \cap X) \cup Y \setminus (Y \setminus (B \cap Y)) = B.$